# How to fix my deprecated use of gluOrtho2D()?

Tags: macos, opengl

I've got existing code (OS X, Obj-C, NSOpenGLView) that calls:

```
gluOrtho2D(0.0, newSize.width, newSize.height, 0.0);
```

It works fine except that I get a deprecated function warning that urges me to use GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho() instead.  OK – but how?  I can't seem to even find the existence of that function; I'm including:

```
#import <OpenGL/gl.h>
#import <OpenGL/glu.h>
```

and Xcode does not know of a function by that name.  My OpenGL reference manual does not have any mention of it, or indeed, of any functions with the prefix GLK; what's going on there?  And then if I managed to find the function and include the right header and link against whatever I need to link against, what then – what would an equivalent call be for GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho() that would do the same thing as my gluOrtho2D() call?  I tried Googling, and found many hits showing that other people are getting the same deprecation warning, but I couldn't find anybody saying how to fix it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The include you need for `GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho()` is:

```
#include <GLKit/GLKMatrix4.h>
```

Then you call the function with the same arguments you would use with `glOrtho()`, e.g.:

```
GLKMatrix4 orthoMat = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

How you use it depends on the kind of OpenGL you use. For fixed function with the legacy matrix stack, you can use for example:

```
glLoadMatrix(orthoMat.m);
```

With the programmable pipeline, you would typically load it as a uniform:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, orthoMat.m);
```

Comment: The context is:

    glViewport(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, newSize.width, newSize.height, 0.0);

The previous commenter @duskwuff said GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho would not "drop in" to code like this, I'd need to upgrade my code to OpenGL 3.2 across the board for it to work.  Do you agree with that?  I don't understand the comment you put on his reply; I'm very new to OpenGL.  (And is there a way to make my comment format better??)

Comment: I disagree with that part of the previous answer. You should be able to replace the `glLoadIdentity()`/`gluOrtho2D()` calls with the `GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho()`/`glLoadMatrix()` above. With the matching arguments, of course. Don't worry about my other comment, that was more about a technicality.

Comment: OK, I switched to `GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho()` / `glLoadMatrix()` and it looks like it is working without other modifications to my code.  Warning gone.  The only hiccup was that it looks like the function is named `glLoadMatrixf()`, not `glLoadMatrix()` – or am I misunderstanding?  Anyhow, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Wow, that's a really unusual recommendation. [`GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKMatrix4/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho) is **not** a drop-in replacement for `gluOrtho2D()`; it's a function that would be used here if you were porting your application to OpenGL 3.2 or later. However, that port would be a much bigger task than just changing out this one call, as OpenGL 3.2 does not support any of the immediate mode APIs from earlier versions of OpenGL (e.g, `glBegin()`).

Bottom line is, so long as you continue to use OpenGL 1.x/2.x APIs, you will need to ignore this warning.

Comment: `glBegin()` is unrelated to whether you use the fixed function pipeline or not. It's part of the immediate mode rendering API. It works perfectly fine with the programmable pipeline in versions that support it (e.g. OpenGL 2.1, or the 3.x compatibility profile). People often throw immediate mode rendering and the fixed pipeline into the same bucket because they were deprecated at the same time, but they are really unrelated. For example ES 1.1 had a fixed pipeline, but no immediate mode rendering.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Changed "fixed-function" to "immediate mode"; brain fart. That being said, if I'm not mistaken OpenGL 3.2 (required for GLKit)  drops support for compatibility profiles altogether? So it's kind of a moot point.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one alternative to disable OpenGL deprecation warnings on `macOS 10.15` and `Xcode 11.2.1`:

**main.c**

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
```

Another alternative would be via `Build Settings`:

[image]